# Fluid go through container when it's moving

Tags: mesh, fluid-simulation

I'm having a problem. As you can see on the pictures, my liquid simulation passes through the glass when the glass is moving.

I tried to invert normals, to increase the surface thickness of the glass, which is 1.7 right now. I tried to increase the resolution but my slow computer crashes when th resolution is over 150.

Here is the link of the project : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SJrqjgY-hx5VYZCWBFuPyjOPrvSl9rqg/view?usp=sharing

I don't know why and I didn't find any answers on YouTube or here so if someone has any tips I would really appreciate ;)
[image: First screenshot of the glass]

[image: Second screenshot of the glass with fluid passes through]

[image: Third screenshot of domain properties]

Comment: I noticed your time scale is changed, but that may not have any effect here. I think your best shot maybe to increase substeps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe free your data and bake again?

I baked your animation just with resolution 50 (and no other change) and i got:

[image]

Just changing a property is often not enough for the simulation to update. Often you have to bake the whole simulation again to see the change.

Comment: Hey ! thx a lot for your answer. That's weird last time I tried the simulation would not start with a low res number but yes that's working but the glass is filling up slowly I didn't know that the res number had an influence on the quantity of liquid baked. Thx a lot btw ;)

Comment: You are welcome. The higher the number the better the quality. I just put it down because I am impatient and it took too long….

Comment: oops sorry its my first time on the forum ;)

Comment: No problem. Thanks!!